# Why does this Postgres Select Query work in the local Docker Container but not on Amazon RDS Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-rds, rails-postgresql, postgresql-9.6

My team has a local development environment that contains a Ruby on Rails app that connects to a Postgres database to retrieve some information about airports and use that to make further queries.  The local environment is meant to duplicate our production environment (both running in the same docker containers).

The local Postgres container is using the official Postgres:9.6-alpine container found here: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

The query in question is:

```
SELECT airports.iata FROM "routes" INNER JOIN "regions" ON "regions"."id" = "routes"."origin_id" INNER JOIN "airports_regions" ON "airports_regions"."region_id" = "regions"."id" INNER JOIN "airports" ON "airports"."id" = "airports_regions"."airport_id";
```

### Local Query Execution

1. The above command executes properly when called by our rails app locally.
2. I can also run the command using psql after "docker exec -it'ing" into the Postgres container locally.

### Amazon RDS Postgres Query Execution

1. In production our Rails app attempts to run the query in question but returns an empty data set: {}

> It should be noted that it successfully connects to the DB and
>   "successfully" makes the query after properly authenticating, so
>   really the issue here is that the query doesn't properly return / match the data.

2. When I manually connect to our Amazon RDS Postgres database using psql, I can properly authenticate, and I can execute the query but I again receive the null / {} result.  All other queries appear to work.

In both of the above cases the query executes properly.  When executing manually it specifically returns the following:

```
iata 
------ 
(0 rows)
```

### Other Interesting facts

1. Point local rails container at Production RDS Postgres — Result: Postgres returns {} even though the Postgres containers COULD execute that same query and return expected list of data when pointed at the local DB.  Returned result in this case reproduces the production behavior: {}
2. SSH into Amazon EC2 instance connected to RDS DB in the same VPC / Security group and run the above command to make sure it was not a permissions problem — Result: Same as remote query: {}
3. Counting the table on both instances (both return the same result ~5880):
   $ SELECT COUNT(*) FROM airports;
4. Listing tables returns identical table list on both Amazon RDS and local Postgres

## Moving forward

At this point I am operating under the assumption that there must be differences between how Amazon RDS for Postgres handles data vs the local Postgres 9.6 db but I haven't been able to find any indication of this on le google. Hopefully some has run into something similar.

## Postgres Versions

SELECT version(); returns the following:

#### RDS Postgres Version

> PostgreSQL 9.6.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2
>   20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit (1 row)

#### Local Postgres Version

> PostgreSQL 9.6.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine
>   6.2.1) 6.2.1 20160822, 64-bit (1 row)

## StackOverflow Suggestions w/ Results

***From @Aleroot Modify Query to:***

```
SELECT a.iata FROM routes ru JOIN regions re ON re.id = ru.origin_id JOIN airports_regions ar ON ar.region_id = re.id JOIN airports a ON a.id = ar.airport_id;
```

#### Result: (Same)

```
 iata 
------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: how do you ssh to RDS?..

Comment: @vao You can't SSH to RDS but you can SSH to an ec2 instance connected to RDS and then use psql commands to connect to the DB once you are into the ec2 instance that resides in the Virtual Private Cloud / security group (that's the closest you can get as far as I know).

Comment: just *ssh to ec2/rds* looks bad - sorry for being picky

Comment: any inner join with not matching id cut out rows - so it is not enough to compare count on airports... try replacing to outer joins to see - maybe some table missing matches for airports?..

Comment: Are you sure you have the same data set? Can you share the schema for the relevant tables? What is the type of the ids? Anything peculiar about them, like sensitivity to different locales? That would be unusual for an id, but you never know... Have you tried removing tables one at a time from the query to see at which point it fails (or starts to return something)?

Comment: @VaoTsun I swapped it to Left Outer Join and was able to return the full list of airports (5880) using the following query.  The number of airports returned by each query (local and on RDS) was the same: 

SELECT airports.iata FROM "routes" RIGHT JOIN "regions" ON "regions"."id" = "routes"."origin_id" INNER JOIN "airports_regions" ON "airports_regions"."region_id" = "regions"."id" RIGHT JOIN "airports" ON "airports"."id" = "airports_regions"."airport_id";

Comment: so one/some of regions, airports_regions, routes has different rows comparing local and docker dbs

Comment: @VaoTsun you are correct. If you want to post an answer about running selects on each table individually I will accept it, after doing selects on each of the tables the local copy properly returned results for everything while some of the intermediate relation tables were missing in production.

Comment: @Necevil I did so. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as we spoke in comments, you can check if the result was not influenced by other tables. Changing `INNER JOIN` to `OUTER JOIN` will append rows with nulls for missing keys, thus amount of rows of airports table will full. Either from the result, or just by checking counts on `regions, airports_regions, routes` tables should reveal the difference between RDS and local databases.

Answer (score 1):

Since @VaoTsun's comment originally got me on the correct path I accepted his answer (also found here).

The real question, which I should have been asking, actually ended up being "How can I make sure that a DB dump that I imported into Amazon RDS Postgres is intact?"

Much of the confusion here resulted from the fact that Amazon RDS did not throw any errors when I imported the dump, and that the web facing portion of my Rails app properly showed almost all data.

This was because MOST tables were imported properly with all data and ALL tables were created.  Therefore listing the tables / schema resulted in everything looking correct and all queries against all but one table resulted in correct answers.

I finally went back through and selected all on each table in the DB:
SELECT * FROM each_table_name;

One specific table returned no results on the remote RDS Database while it returned the expected results locally.  Once this happened I dropped the database out of Amazon RDS and re-imported everything.  No errors during import (again just like last time) but all tables exist with data this time around after selecting all in each table one by one to verify the data imported properly.